# Entity Framework gargantuan SQL from simple LINQ

Tags: entity-framework, frameworks, entity

There are some ~ 10 basic models in my project, and some that inherit from eachother.
Among others I have File, User, Group, all of which have ReadAccess and WriteAccess which relates to a Group. All inherit from File. File also has an Address string property.

I have a LINQ-query that is generated from a couple of helper functions that return Expression-trees. One of the expression trees returned is basically

```
dbContext.Files.Where(f => f.Address == "somepath" && (f.ReadAccess == null || [4].Contains(f.ReadAccess.Id) || f.WriteAccess == null || [4].Contains(f.WriteAccess)).ToList()
```

This generates a gargantuan SQL query. I'm wondering what all the NULL as varchar/varbinary and why is this generated for every single type of File when they are in the same table? It seems quite abundant. Does it slow the SQL query in executing or is it optimized away by the SQL parser? Are there any pitfalls when generating Expression trees to LINQ to SQL? Why does the SQL query generate cases for Folder when Folder does not inherit from File, and I'm only asking for Files?

Using the newest EF (6.1).

```
Alumis_SELECT 
    [Filter1].[Id1] AS [Id], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN '0X0X0X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN '0X0X1X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN '0X0X2X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN '0X1X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN '0X0X3X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN '0X0X3X0X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN '0X0X4X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN '0X0X5X0X' WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN '0X1X0X' ELSE '0X1X0X0X' END AS [C1], 
    [Filter1].[Name1] AS [Name], 
    [Filter1].[Modified1] AS [Modified], 
    [Filter1].[IsDeleted1] AS [IsDeleted], 
    [Filter1].[Address1] AS [Address], 
    [Filter1].[SortOrder1] AS [SortOrder], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[GivenName1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C2], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[Surname1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C3], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[EmailAddress1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C4], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[Password_Salt1] END WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) END AS [C5], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[Password_Hash1] END WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varbinary(1)) END AS [C6], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN [Filter1].[Headline1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C7], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN [Filter1].[Lead1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C8], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN [Filter1].[Body1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C9], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN [Filter1].[ProviderType1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[ProviderType1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C10], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN [Filter1].[ProviderData1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[ProviderData1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C11], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN [Filter1].[ContentType1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[ContentType1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C12], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN [Filter1].[Size1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[Size1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS bigint) END AS [C13], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[Width1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C14], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[Height1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C15], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN [Filter1].[FocalPoints1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS varchar(1)) END AS [C16], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN [Filter1].[IsEnabled1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS bit) END AS [C17], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN [Filter1].[Interval1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS time) END AS [C18], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN [Filter1].[NextScheduledTime1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) END AS [C19], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN [Filter1].[LastStarted1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) END AS [C20], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN [Filter1].[LastCompleted1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS datetimeoffset) END AS [C21], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN [Filter1].[Id2] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C22], 
    CASE WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Group') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'User') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Article') THEN [Filter1].[Author_Id1] WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Folder') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Blob') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Image') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Role') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) WHEN ([Filter1].[Discriminator1] = N'Website') THEN CAST(NULL AS int) END AS [C23], 
    [Filter1].[Language_Id1] AS [Language_Id], 
    [Filter1].[ParentFolder_Id1] AS [ParentFolder_Id], 
    [Filter1].[ReadAccess_Id1] AS [ReadAccess_Id], 
    [Filter1].[WriteAccess_Id1] AS [WriteAccess_Id]
    FROM   (SELECT [Extent1].[Id] AS [Id1], [Extent1].[Name] AS [Name1], [Extent1].[Modified] AS [Modified1], [Extent1].[IsDeleted] AS [IsDeleted1], [Extent1].[Address] AS [Address1], [Extent1].[SortOrder] AS [SortOrder1], [Extent1].[GivenName] AS [GivenName1], [Extent1].[Surname] AS [Surname1], [Extent1].[EmailAddress] AS [EmailAddress1], [Extent1].[Password_Salt] AS [Password_Salt1], [Extent1].[Password_Hash] AS [Password_Hash1], [Extent1].[Headline] AS [Headline1], [Extent1].[Lead] AS [Lead1], [Extent1].[Body] AS [Body1], [Extent1].[ProviderType] AS [ProviderType1], [Extent1].[ProviderData] AS [ProviderData1], [Extent1].[ContentType] AS [ContentType1], [Extent1].[Size] AS [Size1], [Extent1].[Width] AS [Width1], [Extent1].[Height] AS [Height1], [Extent1].[FocalPoints] AS [FocalPoints1], [Extent1].[IsEnabled] AS [IsEnabled1], [Extent1].[Interval] AS [Interval1], [Extent1].[NextScheduledTime] AS [NextScheduledTime1], [Extent1].[LastStarted] AS [LastStarted1], [Extent1].[LastCompleted] AS [LastCompleted1], [Extent1].[Discriminator] AS [Discriminator1], [Extent1].[Author_Id] AS [Author_Id1], [Extent1].[Language_Id] AS [Language_Id1], [Extent1].[ParentFolder_Id] AS [ParentFolder_Id1], [Extent1].[ReadAccess_Id] AS [ReadAccess_Id1], [Extent1].[WriteAccess_Id] AS [WriteAccess_Id1], [Extent2].[Id] AS [Id2], [Extent3].[Id] AS [Id3]
        FROM   [dbo].[FilesAndFolders] AS [Extent1]
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FilesAndFolders] AS [Extent2] ON ([Extent2].[Author_Id] IS NOT NULL) AND ([Extent1].[Id] = [Extent2].[Author_Id])
        LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FilesAndFolders] AS [Extent3] ON ([Extent3].[Discriminator] IN (N'Group',N'User')) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent3].[Discriminator] = N'Group') THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) AND ([Extent1].[ReadAccess_Id] = [Extent3].[Id])
        WHERE ([Extent1].[Discriminator] IN (N'Group',N'User',N'Article',N'Folder',N'Blob',N'Image',N'Role',N'ScheduledIndexTask',N'Website',N'Intranet')) AND (CASE WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Group') THEN '0X0X0X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'User') THEN '0X0X1X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Article') THEN '0X0X2X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Folder') THEN '0X1X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Blob') THEN '0X0X3X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Image') THEN '0X0X3X0X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Role') THEN '0X0X4X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'ScheduledIndexTask') THEN '0X0X5X0X' WHEN ([Extent1].[Discriminator] = N'Website') THEN '0X1X0X' ELSE '0X1X0X0X' END LIKE '0X0X%') ) AS [Filter1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[FilesAndFolders] AS [Extent4] ON ([Extent4].[Discriminator] IN (N'Group',N'User')) AND ((CASE WHEN ([Extent4].[Discriminator] = N'Group') THEN cast(1 as bit) ELSE cast(0 as bit) END) = 1) AND ([Filter1].[WriteAccess_Id1] = [Extent4].[Id])
    WHERE (([Filter1].[Address1] = @p__linq__0) OR (([Filter1].[Address1] IS NULL) AND (@p__linq__0 IS NULL))) AND (([Filter1].[Id3] IS NULL) OR ([Extent4].[Id] IS NULL) OR (([Filter1].[ReadAccess_Id1] IN (4)) AND ([Filter1].[ReadAccess_Id1] IS NOT NULL)) OR (([Filter1].[WriteAccess_Id1] IN (4)) AND ([Filter1].[WriteAccess_Id1] IS NOT NULL)))_p__linq__0=/artikkel-test
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm wondering what all the NULL as varchar/varbinary and why is this
>   generated for every single type of File when they are in the same
>   table?

It looks like you are using Code First approach with the default Table-Per-Hierarchy (TPH) mapping strategy in your solution. In case of TPH, one big table is created for a hierarchy of classes (in your case, `File` & descendants). All non-primary key columns are nullable, because this table contains objects of different types (for example, `User` has a mandatory `GivenName` property, but `Group` does not. Since `User` and `Group` objects are stored in the same table, `GivenName` should be non null for users and null for groups). This explains why your SQL query has so many null checks and casts.

> Why does the SQL query generate cases for Folder when Folder does not
>   inherit from File, and I'm only asking for Files?

It seems like `File` and `Folder` classes depend on each other (i.e., `File` has a property of type `Folder`). In this case, please make sure that you have all prerequisites for [lazy loading.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx)

In general, I strongly recommend avoiding EF if you have a huge hierarchy of classes with many types and deep inheritance. The performance in this case is really, really bad.

If you have no choice but to use EF, you can still improve the performance of your queries. Let's assume that you need only a file name from your query. In this case instead of this:

```
from f in dbContext.Files
where f.Address == "somepath"
select f
```

you can use this:

```
from f in dbContext.Files
where f.Address == "somepath"
select new { f.Name }
```

This will drastically reduce the complexity of a generated SQL query.

Comment: Can you please expand on: "All non-primary key columns are nullable, because this table contains objects of different types (for example, User has a mandatory GivenName property, but Group does not. Since User and Group objects are stored in the same table, GivenName should be non null for users and null for groups)". Where exactly is the rationale? And because File and Folder depend on eachother, it generates this much SQL? I could design an equivalent query without the extra SQL (could I not?), so why exactly do you argue for it?